# How to compile and use adb on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, fastboot

I am following [Google's instructions](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)
to build Android on Ubuntu 12.04.

Somewhere on https://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html it says

> If you don't already have those tools, fastboot and adb can be built
>   with the regular build system. Follow the instructions on the page
>   about Building and Running, and replace the main make command with

```
$ make fastboot adb
```

After using that command, the compile seems to complete fine. I then found an adb binary at

```
 <path>/out/target/product/generic/system/bin/adb
```

However, when I try to use that I get an "cannot execute binary file" error.

Could it be that it was compiled for the wrong architecture? Do I need to configure something (e.g., with lunch) before the "make fastboot adb"?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself. I was looking at the wrong binary. The right one was at

```
<path>/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/adb_intermediates/adb
```

Now

```
adb devices
```

produces a list of devices (with one entry for the phone).